# Visual Studio 2017 - PreBuild event command line (build another project)

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I have a solution with multiple projects.

When I build project 'Foo', I need it to build also project 'SimplePluginFramework' before Foo.

It also needs to build 'SimplePluginFramework' in Release mode, even if Foo is built in debug mode.

I tried adding this to Foo's Pre-build event command line but it's existing with code 9009 and Bar doesn't get built...

```
 $(MSBuildBinPath)\MSBuild.exe "L:\SL1 - Current System\Core\SL Agent\SLV1\Agent\SimplePluginFramework\SimplePluginFramework.csproj" /t:build /p:Configuration=Release
```

How can I make the build of one project trigger the build of a different project before the build?

I've tried adding a reference to that project but it still doesn't build it.

Error:

```
    1>Target "PreBuildEvent" in file "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets" from project "L:\SL1-(SentiLAN)-SentiLAN v1 - Current System\SentilanCore\SentiLAN Agent\SentilanV1\AgentServiceTpl\SentilanService\SentilanService.csproj" (target "CoreBuild" depends on it):
1>Using "Exec" task from assembly "Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core, Version=15.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a".
1>Task "Exec"
1>  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe" "L:\SL1 - Current System\Core\SL Agent\SLV1\Agent\SimplePluginFramework\SimplePluginFramework.csproj" /t:build /p:Configuration=release
1>  Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 15.3.409.57025 for .NET Framework
1>  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
1>  
1>  Build started 15/11/2017 09:47:32.
1>  Project "L:\SL1 - Current System\Core\SL Agent\SLV1\Agent\SimplePluginFramework\SimplePluginFramework.csproj" on node 1 (build target(s)).
1>  GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute:
1>  Skipping target "GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
1>  CoreCompile:
1>  Skipping target "CoreCompile" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
1>  _CopyAppConfigFile:
1>  Skipping target "_CopyAppConfigFile" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
1>  CopyFilesToOutputDirectory:
1>    SimplePluginFramework -> L:\SL1 - Current System\Core\SL Agent\SLV1\Agent\SimplePluginFramework\lib\net35\SimplePluginFramework.dll
1>  Done Building Project "L:\SL1 - Current System\Core\SL Agent\SLV1\Agent\SimplePluginFramework\SimplePluginFramework.csproj" (build target(s)).
1>  
1>  Build succeeded.
1>      0 Warning(s)
1>      0 Error(s)
1>  
1>  Time Elapsed 00:00:00.22
```

Project Dependencies:

[image]

Comment: Don't ask for a manual when the only problem is that you have a silly error message.  Look in the Output window for the message and copy/paste it into your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Project | Project Dependencies to define that Foo depends on SimplePluginFramework.

Use solution configuration (right click on solution and select properties) to define that in solution level Debug configuration Foo's debug build is used but SimplePluginFramework's release build is used.